# Search string in a table Excel

Tags: excel

How can i check if a string is in one of the cells in some column?

```
 A  B     C
acf     rtr gfg 
        g trt  hgh
        gg er5 aa
        acf
        ryyn
```

e.g if "acf" is in one of the C cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a formula in a cell

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("acf",C:C,0)),"Not Found","Found")
```